# nasm Intel: Access items in the stack without using pop

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, nasm, stack-memory

Suppose I want to see the top two elements in the stack without using POP.

How can I access it - I am trying:

```
mov ebp, esp
mov eax, [ebp]
mov ebx, [ebp-4]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PUSH` pre-decrements the stack pointer, and `POP` post-increments it. So to peek at the top two DWORDS:

```
mov eax, [esp]    ; Top of stack
mov ebx, [esp+4]  ; Second element on the stack
```

Comment: I was doing this in a subroutine, so I also needed to keep in mind that [esp] contained a memory address for my return. So the "top two" items in my stack I was interested in were actually [esp+4] and [esp+8]