# Access stack directly

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm

This question is related to [nasm Intel: Access items in the stack without using pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907924/nasm-intel-access-items-in-the-stack-without-using-pop)

My data,code & stack segments are setup before in order to cover full memory.

I try to access the stack directly with the following code:

```
[bits 32]
[org 0x0]

mov ah, 0x62
mov al, 'H'
push ax

mov esi, 0x90000 ;(esp is 0x90000)
sub esi, 4

mov word ax, [esi]

mov word [0xB8A00], ax
jmp $
```

It should print an H, but it prints nothing. I can't get what i'm doing wrong, I also tried removing the **sub esi, 4**, same result. I also tried to switch ah & al content (I kept this order because of little endian)

Comment: `push ax` only decreases ESP by 2, not 4; maybe you meant `push eax`.  Use a debugger to look at register values and memory contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> mov esi, 0x90000 ;(esp is 0x90000)
> ```

This is the worrying part of your code. Eventhough you say that "esp is 0x90000", a defensive programmer would have written it as `mov esi, esp`. In doing so you avoid the problem of **knowing too much**.

The code that places the character code and attribute byte on the stack, will leave the stackpointer pointing at the pair of bytes. This remains true whether you use `push ax` or `push eax`.

Provided you have linear access to memory, are sure that `DS` is equal to `SS`, and that the screen is set correctly (*), next snippet will place the GreenOnBrown capital "H" in the first column of the seventeenth row of the screen:

```
mov  ah, 0x62
mov  al, 'H'
push ax
mov  esi, esp
mov  ax, [esi]
mov  [0xB8A00], ax
```

As an alternative, use the `ESP` relative addressing:

```
mov  ah, 0x62
mov  al, 'H'
push ax
mov  ax, [esp]
mov  [0xB8A00], ax
```

(*) Always ask yourself if the address in video memory is amongst the addresses whose content is used by the hardware to update the screen!

- For the 80x25 text screen, the hardware could be updating from a display page other than the display page 0 that you expect.
- For the 40x25 text screen, the address 0xB8A00 falls outside of the displayed buffer.

Comment: I was trying to not using esp register on purpose for school reason and to understand how the stack works. This is well explained and will probably help a lot of students. Thank you for this clear explanation.